# Need a Text Label Pin For Google Map

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I'm working on a project that requires a list of items located on a map - this will need pins that show what the items are. Tried many different code snippets before but cant seem to get a working version. Any help would be great.

The link below was of the best - but have been having problems implementing it into my project. Screen just is blank.

http://codepen.io/TheMarufm/pen/ywFDe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Complex icons</title>

    <style>
    html, body, #map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>


      <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    <script>
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.808846, 144.963435)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);


var pinz = [
    {
        'location':{
            'lat' : -37.807817,
            'lon' : 144.958377
        },
        'lable' : 2
    },
    {
        'location':{
            'lat' : -37.807885,
            'lon' : 144.965415
        },
        'lable' : 42
    },
    {
        'location':{
            'lat' : -37.811377,
            'lon' : 144.956596
        },
        'lable' : 87
    },
    {
        'location':{
            'lat' : -37.811293,
            'lon' : 144.962883
        },
        'lable' : 145
    },
    {
        'location':{
            'lat' : -37.808089,
            'lon' : 144.962089
        },
        'lable' : 999
    },
];



for(var i = 0; i <= pinz.length; i++){
   var image = 'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2238%22%20height%3D%2238%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2038%2038%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23808080%22%20stroke%3D%22%23ccc%22%20stroke-width%3D%22.5%22%20d%3D%22M34.305%2016.234c0%208.83-15.148%2019.158-15.148%2019.158S3.507%2025.065%203.507%2016.1c0-8.505%206.894-14.304%2015.4-14.304%208.504%200%2015.398%205.933%2015.398%2014.438z%22%2F%3E%3Ctext%20transform%3D%22translate%2819%2018.5%29%22%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%20style%3D%22font-family%3A%20Arial%2C%20sans-serif%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3B%22%20font-size%3D%2212%22%20text-anchor%3D%22middle%22%3E' + pinz[i].lable + '%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E';


   var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pinz[i].location.lat, pinz[i].location.lon);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      icon: image
  });
}

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

If anyone has a better version or whats wrong with my code above, please say.

Comment: duplicate of [Custom SVG Pin with Label in Google Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817080/custom-svg-pin-with-label-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to include the google-maps api script.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

and put all your current code inside a `function initMap(){...}`

Also note that you need to obtain a key from google for this. (*go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/ and press the "GET A KEY" button at the top right*)

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Complex icons</title>

  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #map-canvas {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCDoaEePBvT1DihoTbun8NKSwWss7MzfgI&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="map-canvas"></div>

  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.808846, 144.963435)
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);


      var pinz = [{
          'location': {
            'lat': -37.807817,
            'lon': 144.958377
          },
          'lable': 2
        },
        {
          'location': {
            'lat': -37.807885,
            'lon': 144.965415
          },
          'lable': 42
        },
        {
          'location': {
            'lat': -37.811377,
            'lon': 144.956596
          },
          'lable': 87
        },
        {
          'location': {
            'lat': -37.811293,
            'lon': 144.962883
          },
          'lable': 145
        },
        {
          'location': {
            'lat': -37.808089,
            'lon': 144.962089
          },
          'lable': 999
        },
      ];



      for (var i = 0; i < pinz.length; i++) {
        var image = 'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2238%22%20height%3D%2238%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2038%2038%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23808080%22%20stroke%3D%22%23ccc%22%20stroke-width%3D%22.5%22%20d%3D%22M34.305%2016.234c0%208.83-15.148%2019.158-15.148%2019.158S3.507%2025.065%203.507%2016.1c0-8.505%206.894-14.304%2015.4-14.304%208.504%200%2015.398%205.933%2015.398%2014.438z%22%2F%3E%3Ctext%20transform%3D%22translate%2819%2018.5%29%22%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%20style%3D%22font-family%3A%20Arial%2C%20sans-serif%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3B%22%20font-size%3D%2212%22%20text-anchor%3D%22middle%22%3E' + pinz[i].lable + '%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E';


        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pinz[i].location.lat, pinz[i].location.lon);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          icon: image
        });
      }
    }
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but is the function initMap(){...} Javascript. Could you give an example

Comment: @MarkJames if you notice in the `script` tag i posted there is a `&callback=initMap`. This tells the google maps api that once loaded (*and thus is ready to be used*) to call a global function named `initMap`. You can change that name to whatever you want, and your google maps code should go inside that function.

Comment: Updated answer with full updated code (*change the KEY*)

Answer (score 0):

That Codepen is using a the external javascript file for google maps. To see it, click the cog icon in the upper left corner of the Javascript pane:

[image]

Then you should see the script being used:

[image]

See the Google Maps API guide [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) for more information. Especially [getting an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

In order to just get it running quickly (in the short-term) add the *script* tag for that URL in the HTML before the inline *script* tag (i.e. `<script> var mapOptions = {`):

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

See it in action in the snippet below. But then follow [that guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) and [get an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) for your site.

```js
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 16,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.808846, 144.963435)
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
var pinz = [{
    'location': {
      'lat': -37.807817,
      'lon': 144.958377
    },
    'lable': 2
  },
  {
    'location': {
      'lat': -37.807885,
      'lon': 144.965415
    },
    'lable': 42
  },
  {
    'location': {
      'lat': -37.811377,
      'lon': 144.956596
    },
    'lable': 87
  },
  {
    'location': {
      'lat': -37.811293,
      'lon': 144.962883
    },
    'lable': 145
  },
  {
    'location': {
      'lat': -37.808089,
      'lon': 144.962089
    },
    'lable': 999
  },
];
for (var i = 0; i <= pinz.length; i++) {
  var image = 'data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%2238%22%20height%3D%2238%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2038%2038%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23808080%22%20stroke%3D%22%23ccc%22%20stroke-width%3D%22.5%22%20d%3D%22M34.305%2016.234c0%208.83-15.148%2019.158-15.148%2019.158S3.507%2025.065%203.507%2016.1c0-8.505%206.894-14.304%2015.4-14.304%208.504%200%2015.398%205.933%2015.398%2014.438z%22%2F%3E%3Ctext%20transform%3D%22translate%2819%2018.5%29%22%20fill%3D%22%23fff%22%20style%3D%22font-family%3A%20Arial%2C%20sans-serif%3Bfont-weight%3Abold%3Btext-align%3Acenter%3B%22%20font-size%3D%2212%22%20text-anchor%3D%22middle%22%3E' + pinz[i].lable + '%3C%2Ftext%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E';

  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(pinz[i].location.lat, pinz[i].location.lon);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```